# Batch Jobs Best Practice: Generic or specific?

Tags: apex, batch, bestpractice

In Salesforce's [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) document there is an example of a Batch class for deleting records:

```
global class BatchDelete implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
   public String query;

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
      delete scope;
      DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}
```

And then: *This code calls the BatchDelete batch Apex class to delete old documents. The specified query selects documents to delete for all documents that are in a specified folder and that are older than a specified date. Next, the sample invokes the batch job.*

```
BatchDelete BDel = new BatchDelete();
Datetime d = Datetime.now();
d = d.addDays(-1);
// Replace this value with the folder ID that contains
// the documents to delete.
String folderId = '00lD000000116lD';
// Query for selecting the documents to delete
BDel.query = 'SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE FolderId=\'' + folderId + 
    '\' AND CreatedDate < '+d.format('yyyy-MM-dd')+'T'+
    d.format('HH:mm')+':00.000Z';
// Invoke the batch job.
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(BDel);
System.debug('Returned batch process ID: ' + batchProcessId);
```

What I usually did or do, is create a quite specific Batch class (e.g. `DeleteOldDocumentsBatch` ) which does one thing and then I only start it from whereever I need it. Without passing a query or anything when calling the batch class...

**My question:**

Is that bad practice? Is it recommended to try to create more generic Batch classes which then can be used for multiple purposes by passing different arguments? Or does it not really make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

This is purely opinion:

Where you have common functionality, provide an abstract base class (implementing Database.Batchable) and put that functionality in that base class. Then provide specific-to-type extensions of that base class that you then use.

The reason for this is two-fold:

1. As a developer you minimize code duplication
2. As an admin you can track what processing is actually happening with some clarity.

An admin can see exactly which batches were executed based on the class name in the Apex Jobs list. If you have a single class that varies its behaviour radically based on constructor parameters only you cannot tell, from the captured data (outside the debug logs), which batch execution was which.

If you're a subscriber using an ISV's package and they do this sort of thing (using generic batch classes driven by parameters), you're hosed because you cannot see debug logs for what happens in their package.

Answer (score 2):

Specific not generic.

That documentation example IMHO results in a lot of `Database.Batchable` implementations that use dynamic SOQL that would be better off using static SOQL. Static SOQL is compile-time checked, much easier to format clearly, and supports complex bind variables. In general in Apex code, it should be the first choice unless there is something in the required logic that prevents it being used.

From a design viewpoint, it also makes sense to encapsulate all the logic in the one `Database.Batchable` class. Usually code gets better when more classes are added - see e.g. the [single-responsibility principle](https://codeburst.io/understanding-solid-principles-single-responsibility-b7c7ec0bf80).

For your case the class might look like this:

```
public class BatchDocumentDelete implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

   // Could be just a single folder Id but if multiple folders need the delete
   // doing, makes more sense to just use a single job for all of them
   private Set<Id> folderIds;
   private DateTime beforeDateTime

   public BatchDocumentDelete(Set<Id> folderIds, DateTime beforeDateTime) {
       this.folderIds = folderIds;
       this.beforeDateTime = beforeDateTime;
   }

   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      return Database.getQueryLocator([
          select Id
          from Document
          where FolderId in :folderIds
          and CreatedDate < :beforeDateTime
      ]);
   }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
      delete scope;
      DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
   }

   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
   }
}
```

and the execution can then be started like this:

```
Database.executeBatch(new BatchDocumentDelete(
    new Set<Id>{'00lD000000116lD'},
    DateTime.now()
));
```

Comment: Hey Keith, What do you think of this approach?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/304404/19118

Comment: I regard implementing the `Database.Batchable` as routine, idiomatic Apex, and not something that needs a dedicated class for. Is the `tmpVar1` naming what the `getQuery` method returns? Seems like code depending on an undocumented implementation detail of the platform - only an approach to take when there are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Phil. But if you just want to use in your org to achieve data cleaning or so then it's ok.

I usually do as less code requires for a multiple goals - specially in data cleaning. But I always add some restrictions like:

- Allow batch class to delete only defined object's records.
- Empty Recycle Bin in other operation/execution not in the same. In case if data deleted accidentally then you will be able to restore it.
- Add field and object level security along with sharing.
- Notify when job is finished to know if someone else is doing the same. Or you can add profile/user level check in code as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part you worry about `query` and `execute`. 
So why not make a single generic batch and dynamically inject the query and executioner. In this way in future you only have to write and test the executioner,  that's it.

The responsibility of batch is to call start, execute and finish. Whatever you do in execute does not actually test the working of the batch. It will test the execution of your code. So why not move it to a different class?.

Sometime back I made a generic batch that takes advantage of this. You can refer it.

**Batch:**

```
public class GenericBatch implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>{
    private Object tmpVar1,tmpVar2,tmpVar3,tmpVar4,tmpVar5,tmpVar6;
    private List<Object> tmpVarList = new List<Object>{tmpVar1,tmpVar2,tmpVar3,tmpVar4,tmpVar5,tmpVar6};
    private String query;
    private List<Object> arguments;
    private IExecutioner executioner;

    public GenericBatch(String query , List<Object> arguments ,IExecutioner executioner ){
        this.query = query;
        this.arguments = arguments;
        this.executioner = executioner;
        if(!arguments.isEmpty()){
            tmpVar1 = arguments[0];
            if(arguments.size() > 1){
                tmpVar2 = arguments[1];
            }if(arguments.size() > 2){
                tmpVar3 = arguments[2];
            }if(arguments.size() > 3){
                tmpVar4 = arguments[3];
            }if(arguments.size() > 4){
                tmpVar5 = arguments[4];
            }if(arguments.size() > 5){
                tmpVar6 = arguments[5];
            }
        }
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return  Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> sObjectList) {
        this.executioner.execute(sObjectList);
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

**IExecutioner:**

```
public interface IExecutioner {
     void execute(List<SObject> sObjects);
}
```

**DeleteExecutioner** :

```
public class DeleteExecutioner implements IExecutioner{

    public void execute(List<SObject> sObjects) {
        delete sObjects;
    }

}
```

And then enqueuing batch:

```
List<Object> arguments= new List<Object> ();
arguments.add(Id.valueOf('0033M000001eO8V'));

String query =  Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id=:(Id)arguments[0]]).getQuery();
System.debug(query);        // SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = :tmpVar1 ;//This tmpVar1 should be present in batch class
Database.executeBatch(new GenericBatch(query,arguments , new DeleteExecutioner()));
```

If you want new batch, then just create a new Logic in class that implements 
`IExecutioner` interface. Thats it sorted.

Comment: @KeithC what do you mean? We can get string query from query locator?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my original comment having realised that. If the names "tmpVar1" etc are not documented (i.e. they are an implementation detail that might change) then relying on those names would only be something to do as a last resort.

Comment: This approach falls foul of the inability to see which processing is happening by inspection of the standard async jobs details and would require your executioner to create its own log objects to resolve this. Using system debug does not work if this was packaged, since the debug details would only be accessible by the package developers and not the subscriber org users.